# Import and Dependency Management in Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I was learning about "import" scope in maven and did a sample project below,

Project_1 POM file :

```
    <dependencyManagement>  
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies> 
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

project_2 POM file :

```
<parent>
<groupId>com.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>    
...
...
<dependencyManagement>  
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
           <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

However, this throws an error stating that the JUnit packages are not available in Project2. When I remove the dependencyManagement tag from project_1 POM file. Everything works fine.
But as per the [maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html),

> This scope is only supported on a dependency of type pom in the
>    section. It indicates the dependency to be
>   replaced with the effective list of dependencies in the specified
>   POM's  section. Since they are replaced,
>   dependencies with a scope of import do not actually participate in
>   limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

I've done as mentioned in the docs, what went wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to use a bill-of-materials (BOM) POM and import that.

Your `Project_1` is the BOM POM in this case, and you include all your project's dependencies in the `<dependencyManagement>` element.  It looks like you're doing this correctly.

To import a BOM POM in your project however, you need both `<dependencyManagement>` and `<dependencies>`.

For example, your `Project_2` `pom.xml` should include:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Imports the bill-of-materials POM. -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Add a dependency from the BOM POM.
        Note: no version or scope is required, it's inherited from the BOM POM! -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the BOM POM definition for the above example:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

There is [documentation about this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) on the Apache Maven website (search for "bom").

**Update:**

BOM POMs and parent POMs are similar but different.  BOM POMs are meant purely for importing dependencies into your project.  Parent POMs are meant for multi-module projects, and allow you to define Maven coordinates, plugins, and dependencies that will be inherited by all of modules using the parent POM.

Here is an example of using an inherited dependency from a parent POM.  Note that there are several elements included here that don't make sense in a BOM POM.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>project1</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Inherited from the parent POM. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the parent POM definition for the above example:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>child1</module>
        <module>child2</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Global dependencies...-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <!--Plugins...-->
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: If that was the case, why to use "import" and then add dependency? I could simply add "dependency" in my project_2. Since I've already defined it "dependencyManagement" in project_1.

Comment: Perhaps I misread your question then, which I thought was about using "import" and BOM POMs.  Yes, you can do something similar with a parent POM in a multi-module project.  I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure you are using Maven version 2.0.9 or later that supports this functionality. 
Second your Project1 Pom.Xml is missing the attribute "packaging" Make sure your packaging and type are of the same name so that it inherits all the dependencies.

Also your artifact Id and group ID has to be the same as your project 1's Pom.xml file for it to import the dependency

When in doubt refer to this link 
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies

Comment: I would say it harder. If someone is really using something before Maven 3.0.5 than it's the fault of the user sorry to say that.

Comment: @khmarbaise Oh yea haha just making sure